# QTip2 display issue in Internet Explorer 9 Quirks mode

Tags: internet-explorer-9, qtip2, quirks-mode

I'm working on a browser plugin that involves injecting some markup into the page, and then displaying a QTip2 tooltip when the mouse is hovered over this markup.

Everything works fine in Firefox (44), Chrome (48) and Internet Explorer (testing with version 9 on Windows Vista) - unless IE is in "quirks mode".

Because the plugin could (potentially) be activated on *any* page, it's quite likely that sometime, somewhere, someone will summon it when using Internet Explorer on a web page that kicks IE into Quirks mode. So I really want to try to come up with a solution to the problems that I'm having.

I have two "demo" pages (JSFiddle isn't really viable with IE in Quirks mode, so these are hosted elsewhere).

The first works exactly as expected, even though it provokes IE into Quirks mode. In other words, it demonstrates the outcome that I'm working towards, though with a simplified version of my "real" configuration (the weird layout reflects the page I'm testing with on my LAN web server). Mouse-over on the buttons to display a tooltip.

[Working tooltip page](http://mnm.getenjoyment.net/IEQuirksModeTest.htm)

The second closely mirrors the issues I'm having with my QTip2-based plugin. When the tooltips appear, they're misaligned, floating high above the buttons:

[Problem page](http://mnm.getenjoyment.net/IEQuirksModeTest4.htm)

[image: Screenshot showing positioning problem]

I don't know what's causing the problem and I've no idea how to combat it, so any advice would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the **position.viewport** value was responsible for the misalignment:

```
position:
{
  viewport: $(window),
...
}
```

Changing the value from **$(window)** to **true** (per the Notes section of the documentation for [position.viewport](http://qtip2.com/plugins#viewport.viewport)) gives a more satisfactory result.